# List of potential origins of host domains through which google bot crawls?

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, web-crawlers

What is the potential list of origins of the host domains through which google bot crawls?

**e.g.:** Like Google cache uses the following domain to crawl the APIs: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/

I want to add those google domains into my APIs, so Google bot easily crawls my website. So bot or crawler don't get cross origin error.

Comment: Google cache is now a crawler.   Google cache displays your cached pages on `webcache.googleusercontent.com` but no crawler ever runs from those domains.   Users that view the cached page may request files from your live website with that domain as a referrer.   Are you worried about that cross domain errors for that situation?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about Googlebot encountering any cross-domain errors that that users wouldn't also see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation, [Googlebot always crawls using either the `googlebot.com` or `google.com` domains.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en)

It's worth mentioning that the documentation also recommends using a reverse DNS lookup on the bot's IP to fully verify the bot's authenticity.